# No documentation found for addQuadCurve(to:control)

Tags: swift, xcode

I have just updated Xcode and it asked me if I wanted have my code corrected to swift 3. I said yes but the following lines of code are a problem:

```
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, CGFloat(coordinateXOrigin + x1), CGFloat(coordinateYOrigin + y1), CGFloat(coordinateXOrigin + x2), CGFloat(coordinateYOrigin + y2))
```

I got error below:

**CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint is unavailable use addQuadCurve(to: control)**

But nowhere can I find any documentation about how to change my code into the new format.

Answer (score 0):

The call has changed from

```
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, x, y, cx, cy)
```

to

```
context.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x:x, y:y), control: CGPoint(x:cx, y: cy))
```

Apple docs are [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/coregraphics/cgcontext/2427151-addquadcurve).    So in the context of the original question:

```
CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(context, CGFloat(coordinateXOrigin + x1), CGFloat(coordinateYOrigin + y1), CGFloat(coordinateXOrigin + x2), CGFloat(coordinateYOrigin + y2))
```

now becomes:

```
context.addQuadCurve(to: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(coordinateXOrigin + x1), y: CGFloat(coordinateYOrigin + y1)), control: CGPoint(x: CGFloat(coordinateXOrigin + x2), y: CGFloat(coordinateYOrigin + y2)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the answer myself. I simply replaced the original coordinates with CGPoints.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you could provide an explicit example.